# Where does the search form come from and how to access it

Tags: theming, forms

I am trying to change the search bar that is displayed on my Commerce Kickstart installation.

When inspecting the website code, the form is build like this:

```
  <form class="contextual-links-region" action="/commerce_kickstart/products" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-display-products-page" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
  <div id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-search_api_views_fulltext">
  <div class="views-widget">
  <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-api-views-fulltext">
       <input placeholder="Search" type="text" id="edit-search-api-views-fulltext" name="search_api_views_fulltext" value="" size="26" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
    </div></div></div>
    <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-display-products" name="" value="Apply" class="form-submit">
   </div></div></div></form>
```

My first question is: Where is this HTML coming from? I kind of know the basics of Drupal theming but I have no idea where this piece of code is coming from.

And now I am trying to access it. For example, I would like to edit the Placeholder "Search" into something else. But I have no idea how to do that.

I tried something like this in my themes template.php:

```
function mytheme_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['views_exposed_form_display_products_page']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Test');
    drupal_set_message('Test');
```

Test gets printed, but nothing happens to the search box.

I have also tried:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form_display_products_page') {
    $form['views_exposed_form_display_products_page']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('KLSDFNSELfhsdfk');
    drupal_set_message('Test');
  }
}
```

Test is not shown and obviously nothing happens. 
Is that even the correct id? I also tried using `views-exposed-form-display-products-page` since that is what is used as 'id=' in the form but nothing happened either.

Comment: Judging from the markup it'll probably be `$form['search_api_views_fulltext']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search');`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this from the .theme php file, But I did do this before by overwriting the input.html.twig file.

In your themes folder, " THEME > templates > form > input.html.twig ", If you are building a new theme, this directory might not be there, You will have to create it in the same order and naming in this case.

Note that "THEME" is the root folder for your theme.

Just do something like this in the input.html.twig file

```
<input {{ attributes }} placeholder="How can we help you?" />{{ children }}
```

---

Please note that this way will alter every input tag used by a form initialization from drupal ( Basically the input tags generated by the modules )